# Use of indirect object in this example?

Tags: gramática

> Meh, siempre y cuando no **le pongan** la etiqueta de "Auténtica comida mexicana", por mí que la gente siga comiendo lo que sea que los haga felices.

I can't figure out what the ***"le"*** is referring to. It seems like it would make sense with just *"pongan"*.

Comment: I don't understand "Meh" at the beginning as well as the final phrase: "le muerde a su pizza de pastor". Are you sure those words are correctly spelled?

Comment: meh is the English word meh, the post is from Reddit, sorry. Le muerde a su pizza de pastor was italicized, you can ignore the phrase.

Answer (score 4):

In the sentence:

- Siempre y cuando no **le** pongan la etiqueta de "Auténtica comida mexicana" por mí que la gente siga comiendo **lo que sea que** los haga felices.

the pronoun "le" refers to any food. This pronoun can be interpreted as cataphoric, since it points to what comes afterwards (unlike what happens here, pronouns are usually anaphoric and refer to something said earlier in the context):

- As long as they don't label **it** as "Authentic Mexican food", as far as I'm concerned people can continue to eat **whatever** makes them happy.

Just like "it" points to "whatever" in my English translation, "le" points to "lo que sea que" (any food that) in the Spanish version.